CosmosDB Query Error Using Partition Key in ASP.NET Core
I am working on an application that extracts objects based on their ID from a NoSQL CosmosDB. The container has the following details:

ContainerName: ScenariosTable
Partition key: /_partitionKey
Type: Non-hierarchical

Here are the relevant methods:
[HttpGet("GetScenario/{scenarioId}")]
public async Task<string> GetScenarioAsync(string scenarioId, [FromQuery] string version = "")
{
    Scenario result;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(version) || string.Equals(version, "undefined"))
    {
        result = await repository.GetItemByQueryAsync(s => s.Id == scenarioId).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    else
    {
        result = await historyRepository.GetItemByQueryAsync(s => s.Id == scenarioId).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    if (result != null)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ApplicationException($"Could not retrieve scenario definition");
    }
}

public async Task<T> GetItemByQueryAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    var result = await GetDocumentsCollectionAsync(predicate).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return result.FirstOrDefault();
}

private async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetDocumentsCollectionAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    IDocumentQuery<T> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(
        this.documentCollectionUri,
        new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true, PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("_partitionKey") })
        .Where(predicate)
        .AsDocumentQuery();

    List<T> results = new List<T>();
    while (query.HasMoreResults)
    {
        results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>().ConfigureAwait(false));
    }

    return results;
}

this is the error:
Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentClientException: Cross partition query is required but disabled. Please set x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition to true, specify x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey, or revise your query to avoid this exception.
ActivityId: 9ce56a2c-d5ec-45d8-ad39-a78ef6f5ffa2, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0, Windows/10.0.20348 documentdb-netcore-sdk/2.11.6
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.GatewayStoreClient.ParseResponseAsync(HttpResponseMessage responseMessage, JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings, DocumentServiceRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.GatewayStoreClient.InvokeAsync(DocumentServiceRequest request, ResourceType resourceType, Uri physicalAddress, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.GatewayStoreModel.ProcessMessageAsync(DocumentServiceRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.ProcessRequestAsync(DocumentServiceRequest request, IDocumentClientRetryPolicy retryPolicyInstance, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.ProcessRequestAsync(String verb, DocumentServiceRequest request, IDocumentClientRetryPolicy retryPolicyInstance, CancellationToken cancellationToken, String testAuthorization)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.DocumentQueryExecutionContextBase.ExecuteQueryRequestInternalAsync(DocumentServiceRequest request, IDocumentClientRetryPolicy retryPolicyInstance, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.DocumentQueryExecutionContextBase.ExecuteQueryRequestAsync(DocumentServiceRequest request, IDocumentClientRetryPolicy retryPolicyInstance, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.DefaultDocumentQueryExecutionContext.ExecuteOnceAsync(IDocumentClientRetryPolicy retryPolicyInstance, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.DefaultDocumentQueryExecutionContext.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<<ExecuteInternalAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.ExecuteRetryAsync(Func`1 callbackMethod, 

I tried to set in FeedOptions the parameter "EnableCrossPartition" to true but it is still not working

new FeedOptions { 
  MaxItemCount = -1, 
  EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true, 
  PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("_partitionKey") })
        

This is both specifying EnableCrossPartitionQuery and also specifying PartitionKey, it's one or the other.
The PartitionKey parameter should have the Partition key Value, not the path. If your container is partitioned by /_partitionKey then it should have the value of the property _partitionKey for the group of documents you want to query.
For example, if _partitionKey has the name of the country the documents are assigned to, then you should be doing new PartitionKey("USA") to query documents in that country.
If your intent is not to filter by Partition Key, then remove it from the FeedOptions.
As a side note: The SDK you are using (Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core 2.11.6) is going completely out of support in 3 months. Please consider migrating.
References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/sdk-dotnet-core-v2
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/migrate-dotnet-v3?tabs=dotnet-v3


I removed PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("_partitionKey"), but the error persists.

@azurePinco does the error stack trace matches the method you are expecting to be executed? EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true does indeed set the required header. Could it be that the code is going through another unexpected code path?
